# ng-zorro Error: Module not found when trying to run project

Tags: angular14, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using ng-zorro v14.1.1 for my angular 14.2.7. But when I try to run my angular application, I got errors when building the project looking for modules from ng-zorro and identifying it as not found even though the files existed in the project.

Here's the full view of the error:
[image]

Additional detail of the project:

- Angular Electron project
- Angular 14.2.7
- Electron 21.2.0

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for helping!

I tried removing node-modules and re-install ng-zorro-antd using `ng add ng-zorro-antd`, and even `npm install ng-zorro-antd` if it makes a difference but to no avail, I'm still having the issue. Thus, can't run the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. What I did was to install the modules that are mentioned in the error:

I ran the commands:

- `npm i d3-zoom` --> this command gives you hint on what to do next when you're trying to run the project after the installation is finished, and it instructed me to run the next command below:
- `npm i --save-dev` @types/d3-zoom
- `npm i dagre-compound`
- `npm i d3-shape`